# Search Number Range on Website in Python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, numbers, range

Below is a script that searches for a word on a website. In this case, it's "S&P" on https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC.

My question is how can I search for a number range between 2300 and 2400......or number under/greater than 2400. Basically, I'm making a script that tells me when the price reaches a certain point.

thanks for your help!

```
import webbrowser
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC")
content = page.read().decode('utf-8')
if "S&P" in content :
    webbrowser.open("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC")
```

updated 2017-5-16
Person below helped me. Thanks and thanks to all that replied. I tinkerered around and did below.

```
import urllib.request
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC")
content = page.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
val = soup.find("span", {"data-reactid": "36"}).decode_contents(formatter="html")
if val >= "2,400.00":
    webbrowser.open("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following with BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC")
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?p=^GSPC")
>>> content = page.read().decode('utf-8')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
>>> val = soup.find("span", {"data-reactid": "36"}).decode_contents(formatter="html")
>>> val
u'2,402.32'
>>>
```

Then, convert to a float to check whether it matches your breakpoint:

```
>>> val = float(val.replace(',',''))
>>> val
2402.32
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BS4's Beautiful Soup. Use pip to install it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
content=soup(content,'lxml')
stuffs=content.findAll(class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")
#stuffs will contain your stock price. you can check what range its in and stuff with it
```